# Java create object array of numbers in string format

Tags: java, arrays, object, numbers

I'm writing a function for a program and I need to generate a list of numbers in an `Object[]`

For example.

```
Object[] possibilities = functionName(13);
```

Should generate

```
    Object[] possibilities = {"1", "2", "3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13"};
```

How should I go about achieving this?

Comment: Learn about for loops.

Comment: create an array of size given in functionName. Then use a for loop and put the value of the iterator plus one in the corresponding position in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String functionName(int number){
   StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("{");
   for(int i = 1; i <= number; i++){
      str.append(Integer.toString(i)).append(", ");}
   String string = str.toString().trim();
   string = string.substring(0, str.length()-1);
   string += "}";
   return string;
}
```

This should give you the desired string and you just print it.

Comment: Object[i-1] = Integer.toString(i);} should be  obg[i-1] = Integer.toString(i);}

Comment: @ShivamPaw Sorry just changed it, but I think you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method.

```
private Object[] function(int size) {

        Object[] result = new String[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

            result[i] = Integer.toString(i + 1);
        }

        return result;

    }
}
```

Comment: ? I don't think you understood the question

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a method to `print` the results from your `functionName` (that's setting a goal post). Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] possibilities = functionName(13);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(possibilities));
}
```

Then you might implement `functionName` with a basic `for` loop like

```
static Object[] functionName(int c) {
    Object[] ret = new String[c];
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("\"").append(i + 1).append("\"");
        ret[i] = sb.toString();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And when I run the above I get (the requested)

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"]
```

Comment: @ShivamPaw Java arrays are declared that way, they don't print that way.